# postgresql--- add new column in table 1 by comparing with table 2

Tags: postgresql

table 1 has columns (with rows as) like

```
date          product     comment
12.01.2014   1201/sm/pb     yes
13.01.2014   1202/sa/pa     no
14.01.2014   1215/ja/pc     yes
```

table 2 has columns (with rows as) like

```
certificate  name
1201          pencil
1202          pen
1215          parker
```

i want add one column (name) in table 1

```
date          product     comment  name
12.01.2014   1201/sm/pb     yes     pencil
13.01.2014   1202/sa/pa     no      pen  
14.01.2014   1215/ja/pc     yes     parker
```

some one please tell me how can i add a column in which rows should satisfy the 
condition (product.table1 = certificate.table2 ==> name in table1)

thank u

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to join the tables on the prefix of the `product` column.

```
select t1.date, t1.product, t1.comment, t2.name
from table_1 t1
  joint table_2 t2 on left(t1.product, strpos(t1.product,'/') - 1) = t2.certificate;
```

Comment: in table1 i have 20,000 objects(rows)....after the above operation i am able to extract only 18500 objects.

Comment: can you please tell me any command how to find the missing objects(rows) after the above operation

Comment: @Chanti: then use an outer join ( `left join` instead of just `join`).